# How automatic slug generator could replace accentuated letters?

Tags: url, language

When typing in the title, the automatic slug generator doesn't filter or replace accentuated letters such as (ő, ú, á, ű). Is there a way to replace these letters to the unaccented one (like ő -> o, ű -> u, etc..)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It actually used to work this way when Craft first launched, but we had feedback where it was desired behavior to allow accented characters and even multi-byte characters in slugs, because they are perfectly valid in the URI.  e.g. [http://domain.com/會意字](http://domain.com/%E6%9C%83%E6%84%8F%E5%AD%97)

However, enough people have brought it up where they would like the old behavior that we're going to add a config setting for Craft 2.2 where you can choose which you prefer.

**Update:**

This was added as a [limitAutoSlugToAscii](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#limitAutoSlugsToAscii) config setting that defaults to `true` in Craft 2.2.

Comment: https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#limitAutoSlugsToAscii

Comment: Updated answer... thanks, @JasonGaluten!

Comment: No prob. This answer helped me a lot, so thanks!